# How to convert POJO to MultiValueMap<String, String>?

Tags: java, jackson

I want to convert POJO to `MultiValueMap<String, String>`(RequestParams).

**POJO class:**

```
public class Foo {
  String fooStr;

  int fooInt;

  List<String> fooList;
}
```

Convertion code:

```
public static MultiValueMap<String, String> convert( Object obj ) {
  MultiValueMap<String, String> requestParamMultiValueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
  
  Map<String, String> requestParamMap = new ObjectMapper()
      .convertValue( obj, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {} ); // Exception occurs here
  requestParamMultiValueMap.setAll( requestParamMap );
  
  return requestParamMultiValueMap;
}
```

When `Foo` class has only `String` member variables, it doesn't matter, but `Foo` class has `List<String>` member variable, and it causes

```
IllegalArgumentException: 
  Cannot deserialize value of type java.lang.String
  from Array value (token JsonToken.START_ARRAY).
```

How to convert POJO with `List<String>` field to `MultiValueMap` using Jackson?

Comment: Why would you want to convert something to MultiValueMap yourself?

Comment: @ValerijDobler Because requestParams need MultiValueMap<String, String>

Comment: What is supposed to happen with "fooInt", which is not String?

Comment: To return it at a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done automatically without customization, because the problem is too broad: each type needs to be converted to a list of strings, which is not obvious. Here we have some trivial cases (integer and string), but generally it would be good to control this conversion.

Here is a simple example where first we do a default conversion to `Map<String, Object>`, handled naturally by Jackson; then the custom `if-else` step follows, where each type goes through a special conversion. This step should be extended to fit the exact needs (and types) of the application. I guess proper test coverage would do the trick, because we can't rely 100% on static typing in this case.

It is important to notice that in case the `Collection` has other collections as elements the results depends on each particular collection "toString" method implementation, which probably could give unexpected results.

```
class TestJacksonConvert {

    private static ObjectMapper OM = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test
    void test() {
        var foo = new Foo();
        foo.fooStr = "abc";
        foo.fooInt = 21;
        foo.fooList = List.of("a", "B", "c");

        var converted = convert(foo);

        assertEquals(
            converted,
            Map.of(
                "fooStr", List.of("abc"),
                "fooInt", List.of("21"),
                "fooList", List.of("a", "B", "c")
            )
        );
    }

    public static LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> convert(Object obj) {
        var multiMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();

        Map<String, Object> map = OM.convertValue(obj, new TypeReference<>() {});

        map.forEach((key, value) -> {
            if (value instanceof Collection<?> collection) {
                multiMap.put(key, collection.stream().map(Object::toString).toList());
            } else if (value != null) {
                multiMap.put(key, List.of(value.toString()));
            }
        });

        return multiMap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might a little slow but you can try this.

```
public MultiValueMap<String, String> convertToMultiValueMap(Object pojo) {
MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

Field[] fields = pojo.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    String key = field.getName();
    Object value = field.get(pojo);
    if (value != null) {
        map.add(key, value.toString());
    }
}

return map;
}
```

This method uses reflection to get a list of all the fields in the POJO and adds each field to the map as a key-value pair.

Comment: ```toString()``` on Collection will make them unusable, like ```["[\"data01\", \"data02\"]"]```.